# bash pipe to grep in if statement return value

Tags: bash

i am trying to construct an `if` statement with negation, but it does not behave as i expect.

for instance, the following returns 0 since `bar` is found in the process list

```bash
$ ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep 'bar'
bar

$ cat foo.sh
ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep 'bar'
if ! ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep -q 'bar'; then
  echo "not running"
else
  echo "running"
fi
```

but when `foo.sh` is executed it always outputs `not running`, when `bar` is found in the process list, see below

```bash
$ ./foo.sh
bar
not running
```

if `bar` is not running and the`foo.sh` is executed again, the output is the same.

could you please help understand why it misbehaves?

**update:**

```bash
$ ps aux | grep
foo             32768  13.0  0.5 73686048 159440   ??  S     2:46AM   0:01.90 /home/foo/bar
```

Comment: Take a look at `pgrep`.

Comment: @Cyrus could you please help me with the snippet above?

Comment: Show output of `ps aux | grep bar` in your question (no comment here).

Comment: use `set -x` to see what's happening

Comment: @Philippe — In the POSIX shell, the negation applies to the pipeline, not a single command (see [Pipelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02).)  The same is true in bash (see [Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines).). The `pipefail` option affects Bash.

Comment: Using the command `sleep` instead of `bar` (because `bar` isn't available on the machine), the script worked as expected on a MacBook Pro running Monterey 12.6.7 and using Bash version `3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)`.  It reports `running` when there is a `sleep` command running; it reports `not running` when there is no `sleep` command running.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : True, but we don't have _pipefail_ in effect here. I think the comment by Philippe explains what's going on here.

Comment: @user1934428 — In the light of my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750683/bash-pipe-to-grep-in-if-statement-return-value#comment135311170_76750683), why do you think that?  Please link to (or quote) the relevant section of the Bash manual that contradicts the section I linked to.  I agree that `pipefail` is not directly relevant to this question; it is relevant to the operation of the `!` operator in general, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Oops, you are right, and it seems that Philippe is wrong. I just tried `! true | false`, and indeed, the status code is 0, showing that the pipe (i.e. the last command) is negated. But in this case, I don't understand the observation of the OP: If `bar` is really in the output, `grep` yields exit code 0. This will turn into 1 by the negation operator, and this means that the `else` branch is executed.

Comment: Just an idea: Could it be that `bar` is a program which has a very short execution time, so that the first `ps` still shows it, but the second one (the one which you are actually testing) does not show it anymore? I suggest that you put another `ps` right after printing the _not running_ message.

Comment: @Philippe i was using `pipefail`, is that the reason for the fail? please convert your comment to an answer so it could be accepted

Comment: have you seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) ?

Comment: Please give the relevant information in the question.  Your script doesn't show `pipefail`, and it is not a default option.  It is also crucial to the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is a combination of `pipefail` and `grep -q`, because `grep -q` causes `grep -v` to fail (with a status of 141).

Following snippet works :

```
$ cat foo.sh
set -o pipefail
ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep 'bar'
if ! ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep 'bar' > /dev/null; then
  echo "not running"
else
  echo "running"
fi
```

If you still want to keep `grep -q`, try this

```
$ cat foo.sh
set -o pipefail
ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep 'bar'
if ! (set +o pipefail;ps -e -o command | grep -v grep | grep -q 'bar' ); then
  echo "not running"
else
  echo "running"
fi
```

Comment: JFTR: an exit status of 141 means a process died from SIGPIPE.  POSIX simply says that [`grep -q`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)
 shall not print anything.  On macOS, the manual also says `grep -q` will stop when it finds a match (presumably, that applies on Linux too).  And the `pipefail` is key to this problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You may have misunderstood. I said `grep -q` causes `grep -v` to fail, not `grep -q` itself.

Comment: Yes — I realize that, and you said that `grep -v` exits with status 141 = 128 + 13 and the 13 is the value of SIGPIPE, and that is how the shell indicates that a [program exits due to a signal](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02).  I suspect that it depends in part on where the `bar` command appears in the `ps` output.  If the `bar` line is last, then the signal probably isn't generated; if the `bar` line is first, it may be generated.  It depends on timing and scheduling too.

Comment: I should perhaps have been more explicit.  When `grep -q` exits early, the `grep -v` command writing to it receives a `SIGPIPE` signal because its standard output pipe is closed. The shell treats that as exit status 141 (it adds the signal number — 13 for SIGPIPE — to 128).  Because `pipefail` is set, this becomes the overall status for the pipeline.  By far the best fix is not to set `pipefail` — the desired status is the status of the last `grep` in the pipeline and there is no real interest in the exit status of any earlier command, so `pipefail` is actively counter-productive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OP's script might be in a larger context where `pipefail` is mandatory for other parts of the context. That's the reason why I gave a second example in my solution.